# How to parse rows with variable numbers of columns

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(2949735L, 3041435L, 2972485L, 3038555L, 
2970906L, 3041901L), V2 = c("superkingdom_Bacteria,phylum_Pseudomonadota,class_Alphaproteobacteria,order_Hyphomicrobiales,family_Lichenihabitantaceae,genus_Lichenifustis", 
"superkingdom_Bacteria,phylum_Pseudomonadota,class_Alphaproteobacteria,order_Hyphomicrobiales,family_Beijerinckiaceae,genus_Methylocapsa", 
"superkingdom_Bacteria,phylum_Pseudomonadota,class_Alphaproteobacteria,order_Sphingomonadales,family_Sphingomonadaceae,genus_Sphingomonas", 
"superkingdom_Bacteria,phylum_Pseudomonadota,class_Betaproteobacteria,order_Burkholderiales,family_Burkholderiaceae,genus_Caballeronia", 
"superkingdom_Bacteria,phylum_Pseudomonadota,class_Alphaproteobacteria,order_Rhodospirillales,family_Azospirillaceae,genus_Azospirillum", 
"superkingdom_Eukaryota,kingdom_Viridiplantae,phylum_Chlorophyta,class_Ulvophyceae,clade_TCBD clade,order_Bryopsidales,suborder_Bryopsidineae,family_Bryopsidaceae,genus_Bryopsis"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to "align" my data such that each comma separated value in column two gets separated into a a new column based on the string before the underscore.

Comment: A tricky thing with R is that multiple things can look the same way printed out. (e.g. flat text vs. vector vs. data frame, character vs. factor, etc.)  To make it easier for people to help you with suggestions that actually work for your data, can you please share it in a reproducible way? The `dput()` function is great for this. `dput(head(YOUR_DATA_OBJECT))` will create a code recipe that you can put into your question, allowing us to load the data in exactly the same form you have it in.

Comment: Done. Thanks for this tip!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)
df |>
  separate_rows(V2, sep = ",") |>
  separate(V2, c("level", "value"), sep = "_") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = level, values_from = value)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 6 × 10
       V1 superkingdom phylum         class               order            family               genus         kingdom       clade      suborder     
    <int> <chr>        <chr>          <chr>               <chr>            <chr>                <chr>         <chr>         <chr>      <chr>        
1 2949735 Bacteria     Pseudomonadota Alphaproteobacteria Hyphomicrobiales Lichenihabitantaceae Lichenifustis NA            NA         NA           
2 3041435 Bacteria     Pseudomonadota Alphaproteobacteria Hyphomicrobiales Beijerinckiaceae     Methylocapsa  NA            NA         NA           
3 2972485 Bacteria     Pseudomonadota Alphaproteobacteria Sphingomonadales Sphingomonadaceae    Sphingomonas  NA            NA         NA           
4 3038555 Bacteria     Pseudomonadota Betaproteobacteria  Burkholderiales  Burkholderiaceae     Caballeronia  NA            NA         NA           
5 2970906 Bacteria     Pseudomonadota Alphaproteobacteria Rhodospirillales Azospirillaceae      Azospirillum  NA            NA         NA           
6 3041901 Eukaryota    Chlorophyta    Ulvophyceae         Bryopsidales     Bryopsidaceae        Bryopsis      Viridiplantae TCBD clade Bryopsidineae
```

Comment: Crafty. Thanks!